# Чтение всех строк

Tags: python, ввод

Необходимо найти все целые неотрицательные числа в тексте и вывести их через запятую. Написал код:

```
import re
text = input()
output = re.findall(r"[0-9]+", text)
print(','.join(output))
```

Но ввод может состоять из нескольких строк, что мой код не охватывает и упускает данные, введенные с новой строки. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить ошибку?
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: `re.findall(r"[0-9]+", text, flags=re.MULTILINE)`.

Comment: Здесь нет проблемы с регулярным выражением.

Answer (score 0):

Если ввод должен осуществляться в несколько строк, вы можете изменить эту часть:

```py
text = input()
```

На эту:

```
text = ""
while 1:
  s = input()
  if s:
    text += '\n' + s
  else:
    del s
    text.strip('\n')
    break
```

Ввод будет вводиться, пока не введена пустая строка